# Use a separate history for 'read -e' (readline)

Tags: linux, bash, readline, command-history

I would like to write an interactive command shell in shell script, for easier adjusting of the iptables firewall. The problem is, that `read -e` uses the *shell* history. Is there a way of using a separate history for `read -e` in a script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have `rlwrap` (debian package `rlwrap`), then you could use something like:

```
LINE=$(rlwrap head -n1)
```

which will use the file `~/.head_history` by default. (`man rlwrap` for more details, including options for specifying a history filename.)

Another possibility is to run `read` in a subshell with `HISTFILE` set to your own history file, but you'll need to do a lot more work because although `read -e` *uses* the history, it does not update it. So you'll probably need something like:

```
LINE=$(bash -c 'HISTFILE=/path/to/history_file;
                history -r; read -e LINE;
                history -s "$LINE"; history -w;
                echo "$LINE"')
```

Comment: Yes!! I have `rlwrap`. It is already installed on my Fedora 20 installation. It works!